# AgGrid: does onGridReady fall into line with Angular hooks?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm passing data source to the grid like so:

```
  @Input() id: number;

  public gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    ...
    onGridReady: (event) => this.onGridReady(event)
  };

  public onGridReady(params): void {
    const dataSource = {
      getRows: (rowsParams: IGetRowsParams) => {

        return this.dataService.getData(this.id)
          .subscribe(data => rowsParams.successCallback(data.rows, data.amount))}
    };

    params.api.setDatasource(dataSource);
  }
```

And the template:

```
<ag-grid-angular class="ag-theme-alpine" [gridOptions]="gridOptions"></ag-grid-angular>
```

The questions is - is it safe to use `@Input` variable in `onGridReady` event? The question is probably wider than that, when does `onGridReady` fires accordingly to Angular lifecycle hooks?

P.S. AgGrid version 24 and Angular 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onGridReady` will come after any `ngOnInit` or `@Input()`s. Assuming, of course, that you only load your grid once you have some input.

`onGridReady` will fire once Grid is good and ready. Grid will only get initialised and rendered and whatnot once the component has initialised itself and started to load it. Therefore, `ngOnInit` will always happen before `onGridReady`.

When it comes to `@Input()`s, you can always input different data at any time, so `@Input()` may cause some data refresh or something if that changed at a later date.

However, most usages tend to be something like:

```
<div *ngIf="data">
  <ag-grid-angular
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    [data]="data">
  </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

i.e. only show the grid if you gots some data to show.
That, or a mechanism is in place to appropriately populate the grid and/or handle lack of data, etc.

So long as you're showing whatever component it is only when you have input data available, it will be safe to use that input data on the `onGridReady` event.

```
<div *ngIf="gridData">
  <app-my-grid-component [id]="someId">
  </app-my-grid-component>
</div>
```

```
@Input() public id: number;
...
public onGridReady(params: any): void {
  console.log('id', this.id);
}
```

Otherwise, you'd need to wait for it all to be available properly:

```
private isGridReady: boolean = false;
private gridParams: any;

private _id: number;
@Input() public set id(value: number) {
  this._id = value;
  if (this.isGridReady) this.populateData();
}

public onGridReady(params: any): void {
  this.gridParams = params;
  this.isGridReady = true;
  if (this._id && this._id > 0) this.populateData();
}

private populateData(): void {
  // However you choose to populate the grid...
  this.service.getDataOrSomething(this.id)
    .subscribe((x) => this.gridParams.setRowData(x));
}
```

This approach would allow for having the grid data set at any point; populated if the input is available both before or after the grid is actually ready for it.